# Cassandra comments example model best practice

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

I really want competent specialists to point me in the right direction, due to the lack of serious experience in designing models. So have some questions that i can't find answers to. With your permission, I will first give an example first.

Imagine, that we have some table named `comments`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments (
  disquss_id uuid, //some disqussion
  comment_id timeuuid,
  created_at timestamp,
  user_id uuid,
  comment_text text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((disquss_id), user_id, comment_id),
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (comment_id DESC);
```

If we want to add replies function, i see two ways to do it:
make field `replies` as **map** type, for example `replies map<uuid, reply>`, or make another table `replies` such

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS replies(
      parent_comment_id timeuuid, //comment_id from table `comments`
      comment_id timeuuid,
      created_at timestamp,
      user_id uuid,
      comment_text text,
      PRIMARY KEY ((parent__comment_id ), user_id, comment_id),
    ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (comment_id DESC);
```

**First question:**
Option with `map` field give me advantage to get all replyes at once, but option with table `replies` give advantage of pagination. If we expect, that there will be 10000 replies on one comment, creating a new table is best option. Am i right?

**Second question:** If we decide to use second option with another table `replies`, what best practice to get that replies for comments? If we took 100 first comments, i must make 100 another request to get replyes for that comments. It doesn't seem like the best solution and i'm very confused

**Third question:** Extending the second situation, if we decide to make function for **like** comments, obviously me must use `counters`. We cannot mix counter and non counter columns in the same table, thats why we must created another table 'comments_like'. In that case we must to make request to database for **every single comment**. What to do in that case?

Thanks for any suggestion!